How do I stop react-slick slider image from indefinitely expanding and fit the container?
I am trying to create an image slider / carousel inside of a box. I have got the carousel working, but the image is too small. Whenever the width is adjusted (or infinite is true) the image just expands constantly to where there is just smudge from a zoomed in part of the image, and/or the horizontal scroll basically goes infinitely.
ImageSlider component:
const SliderContainer = styled.div`
  width: 50%;
  .slick-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
`;

const StyledSlider = styled(Slider)`
  width: 100%;

  .slick-prev, .slick-next {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .slick-prev {
    left: 10px;
  }

  .slick-next {
    right: 10px;
  }

  .slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
  }
`;

const ImageSlider = ({ images }) => {
  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
  };

  return (
    <SliderContainer>
      <StyledSlider {...settings}>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <img src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </StyledSlider>
    </SliderContainer>
  );
};

Webpage code:
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Box from '../components/Box';
import ImageSlider from '../components/ImageSlider';
import image1 from '../assets/images/aboutimage1.jpg';
import image2 from '../assets/images/aboutimage2.jpg';
import helpImage from '../assets/images/hair-wash.jpg';
import customerImage from '../assets/images/helping-customer.jpg';
import stylesImage from '../assets/images/styles.jpg';

const AboutContainer = styled.div`
  padding: 6rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
`;

const TopSection = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
`;

const OpeningTimesBox = styled(Box)`
  flex: 1;
`;

const SliderBox = styled(Box)`
  flex: 2;
  position: relative; /* Ensures it respects the container */
`;

const BottomSection = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
`;

const ContentBox = styled(Box)`
  flex: 1;
`;

const About = () => {
  const images = [
    { src: image1, alt: 'Slide 1' },
    { src: image2, alt: 'Slide 2' },
  ];

  return (
    <AboutContainer>
      <TopSection>
        <OpeningTimesBox title="Opening Times">
          <p>Open Six Days A Week Except For Bank Holidays</p>
          <p>Mon-Fri: 9am - 5:30pm</p>
          <p>Sat: 8am - 5pm</p>
          <p>Sun: Closed</p>
          <p>OAP Rates Monday to Thursday</p>
          <p>No Appointment Needed</p>
        </OpeningTimesBox>
        <SliderBox>
          <ImageSlider images={images} />
        </SliderBox>
      </TopSection>

I've adjusted the displays and the height / width to try a variety of combinations, but the image either becomes too small, cut in half, or it expands. Whenever the width values are adjusted, one has to be 50% otherwise it just expands indefinitely.
